# selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to make a script that answers a kahoot randomly, everything is working fine but when the script has to click on the "next" button I get this `error:'selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified'`
I tried searching for this error but nothing that related to my script showed up.

```py
import random
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("kahoot link")
choices= ['//*[@id="challenge-game-router"]/main/div[2]/div[1]/span', '//*[@id="challenge-game-router"]/main/div[2]/div[2]/span', '//*[@id="challenge-game-router"]/main/div[2]/div[3]', '//*[@id="challenge-game-router"]/main/div[2]/div[4]']
try:
    sleep(5)
    nickname= driver.find_element_by_name('nickname')
    nickname.send_keys(username)
    enter = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="challenge-game-router"]/main/section/div[1]/form/button').click()
finally:
    pass


for c in range(0, 3):
    try:
        driver.implicitly_wait(20)
        choice = driver.find_element_by_xpath(random.choice(choices))
        choice.click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(20)
        next = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div/main/button')
        next.click()
    finally:
        pass
```

Comment: What's `choices`? You don't define it in your code.

Comment: @Charles you are right i forgot to copy that part of the code i will edit that, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by copying the Xpath with Firefox instead of Google_Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find element by class name here, but providing xpath to `find_element_by_class_name` funtion, which is why it throws invalid selector exception.

```
next = driver.find_element_by_class_name('/html/body/div/div/div/div/main/button')
```

Either you should provide a valid classname or use `find_element_by_xpath` instead.

Comment: thank you but now i'm getting this error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/div/div/div/main/button"}

Comment: Then probably you need to correct xpath `/html/body/div/div/div/div/main/button`.

Comment: I tried to inspect and copy the xpath and got this one:'//*[@id="challenge-game-router"]/main/button' but i'm still getting the same error (is there another way of getting xpathes and i'm doing it wrong?)

Comment: Ok, so to make sure whether your xpath `//*[@id="challenge-game-router"]/main/button` is correct...enter it in inspect element find bar and see if it highlights button ?

Comment: no, nothing highlited, how is it possible that i am copying the wrong xpath?

Comment: how do i do copy it?

Comment: from inspect element, copy html around that button

Comment: Try this `//button/span[contains(text(),"Next")]`  ...replace buttontext with actual button text. Also verify the same way, it should highlight button if you search it in find bar

Comment: this <button type="approve" class="next-button__Button-sc-1wk6ntg-0 gyJMgf button__Button-c6mvr2-0 hotoYM" data-functional-selector="next-button"><span>Next</span></button>

Comment: i tried searching for this //button[contains(text(),'Next')] and got no highlited button

Comment: Updated my comment, try that now